# Hexagon Polyhedral of Infinite Size

Tags: polygons, polyhedra

I thought of this question after reading a bit about Goldberg polyhedrons.

Does it make sense to suggest that a complete regular polyhedron consisting of only hexagons could exist, given an infinite size?

I don't think so. At least, I suspect it wouldn't be complete, but I'm not sure how to better reason about the question.

Intuitively, it seems as though one would always need other polygons to complete the face. However, in my mind, I can imagine that at any given localized region of the face the tiling resembles a two dimensional plane, so there's no "need" for any other polygons to appear in the face. In such a case, would there be anywhere on the face that would need a pentagon or other polygon to complete the face? If not, wouldn't that mean we've defined a regular polyhedron consisting of only hexagons?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "polyhedron [of] infinite size" even mean?

Comment: If you mean to use e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection to project infinite tiling of a plane (by regular hexagons) to a sphere, sure you can do it. The fact that the hexagons are cyclic means that the (not necessarily regular) hexagons on the sphere will be planar, i.e you can make "faces" out of them. Would it give rise to an "infinite size polyhedron"? Sort of, but whatever this object is, it won't be a polyhedron but something else. Will leave it to others to comment if anyone has seen something like this, and whether it is useful.

Comment: Also note that there is no polyhedron with only hexagonal faces, at least not one that is topologically a sphere. Otherwise, with $F$ faces you will have $3F$ edges and $\le 2F$ vertices, so $F-E+V\le 0$, which is impossible as Euler characteristic of a sphere is $2$.

Comment: That is interesting to think about, thank you!

Comment: The [hexagonal tiling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) is sometimes considered as the infinite "regular polyhedron" with only hexagonal faces. Besides that you would need to make your definition of polyhedron more precise.